# preventing unnecessary namespace into xml

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, kml, vb.net-2010, google-earth

Im working on a project that modifies a kml file by adding gps coordinates on a specific spot in the kml. My code, however, is adding the "gx" namespace on **ALL** of the elements when its saved at the end. I have researched and looked at a ton of different Visual Basic XML writing methods and I've ran out of ideas. How do I stop unnecessary namespaces to be added?!

test.kml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>test.kml</name>
    <Snippet>File Created Mon Jul 9 15:50:16 2012</Snippet>
    <Style id="multiTrack_n">
      <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/track.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LineStyle>
        <color>99ffac59</color>
        <width>6</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
      <Placemark>
        <name>test.kml</name>
        <styleUrl>#multiTrack_n</styleUrl>
        <gx:Track>
          <!--GPS Tracking data Points-->
        </gx:Track>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.DateTime
Imports <xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
Imports <xmlns:gx="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
...
Public Sub addCoordinate(ByVal lon As Double, ByVal lat As Double, ByVal att As Double, ByVal timeStamp As String)
        Dim currentDoc = XDocument.Load("test.kml")
        Try
            whenElement = _
                <when><%= timeStamp %></when>
            coordElement = _
                <gx:coord><%= lon.ToString %>,<%= lat.ToString %>,<%= att.ToString %></gx:coord>
            Dim testLocation = currentDoc.<kml>.<Document>.<Folder>.<Placemark>.Elements.Last()
            testLocation.Add(whenElement)
            testlocation.Add(coordElement)
            currentDoc.Save("test.kml")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

after code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<gx:kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <gx:Document>
    <gx:name>test.kml</gx:name>
    <gx:Snippet>File Created Mon Jul 9 16:40:11 2012</gx:Snippet>
    <gx:Style id="multiTrack_n">
      <gx:IconStyle>
        <gx:Icon>
          <gx:href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/track.png</gx:href>
        </gx:Icon>
      </gx:IconStyle>
      <gx:LineStyle>
        <gx:color>99ffac59</gx:color>
        <gx:width>6</gx:width>
      </gx:LineStyle>
    </gx:Style>
    <gx:Folder>
      <gx:name>test.kml</gx:name>
      <gx:Placemark>
        <gx:name>test</gx:name>
        <gx:styleUrl>#multiTrack_n</gx:styleUrl>
        <gx:Track>
          <!--GPS Tracking data Points-->
          <when xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">2012-07-09T08:40:29Z</when>
          <gx:coord xmlns:gx="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">0,0,0</gx:coord>
          <when xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">2012-07-09T08:40:33Z</when>
          <gx:coord xmlns:gx="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">0,0,0</gx:coord>
          <when xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">2012-07-09T08:40:41Z</when>
          <gx:coord xmlns:gx="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">0,0,0</gx:coord>
        </gx:Track>
      </gx:Placemark>
    </gx:Folder>
  </gx:Document>
</gx:kml>
```

Comment: Why are you declaring the same namespace twice (once as the default and once with the `gx` prefix)?

Comment: Good question. This KML is for Google Earth plotting and the examples used had two name spaces (default and gx). If I take one of them out (especially the default) nothing works. =[

Comment: If all your elements are in the http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 what is the issue with having them explicitly shown rather than default - the XML is equivalent and any conforming parser should deal with it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After realizing what said in the comments, I realized if I have the Default NS in the XML as http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2, every element is assumed to have it, so when I re-save, it applies the namespaces.

Something so small and simple...Silly me... learn something everyday